# Вирус в Symfony?

Tags: symfony, вирусы

В одном из проектов symfony обнаружилась забавная особенность: по какой-то причине логины учеток стали заменяться на неприличные жесты. По логам удалось найти только подобное:

*INSERT INTO users (id, username, roles, password, fio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":1,"2":"","3":["ROLE_ADMIN"],"4":"$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4 [...]","5":""} []*

Уже пробовали откатывать виртуальную машину, на которой расположен проект, но вирус начинает проявлять себя сразу же. Пробовали все сносить и ставить по новой, но вирус начинает проявлять себя через некоторое время. При чем, ни в src, ни в vendor, ни где-либо, кроме логов symfony, нет упоминаний этого жеста, непонятно откуда руки растут. В чем может быть причина? Ведь судя по логам, данный вирусный скрипт как-то через доктрину вносит свои данные, так что полагаю, что внешнее воздействие можно исключить. Еще можно обратить внимание на id в запросе, он почему-то не берется со счетчика, что вызвало исключение и в логах есть следующее:

*request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (id, username, roles, password, fio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, "\ud83d\udd95", "["ROLE_ADMIN"]", "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$4mZlwH3BGqwKNatD4tk/BA$pTJqs0b/8WA8pXnyyb6KxGsGdH/t39V/385reaLOw34", "\ud83d\udd95"]:  SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists." at /home/ubuntu/phpipam/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 70 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (id, username, roles, password, fio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, "\ud83d\udd95", "[\"ROLE_ADMIN\"]", "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$4mZlwH3BGqwKNatD4tk\/BA$pTJqs0b\/8WA8pXnyyb6KxGsGdH\/t39V\/385reaLOw34", "\ud83d\udd95"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists. at /home/ubuntu/phpipam/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php:70)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception(code: 23505): SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists. at /home/ubuntu/phpipam/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 23505): SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists. at /home/ubuntu/phpipam/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:115)"} []*

Comment: Покажите список установленных зависимостей

Comment: _Еще можно обратить внимание на id в запросе, он почему-то не берется со счетчика_ видимо вирус не в симфони, а в шелл скриптах сервера.